# Multiple PostgreSQL instances for one PGDATA folder

Tags: postgresql

Is it possible to have multiple PostgreSQL instances for one PGDATA folder, shared in a storage for example?

And if is not, is there is some kind of RDBMS capable of something like this?

Comment: Do you mean multiple databases within a single cluster? Or multiple clusters? If the latter, where does the requirement come from that they share PGDATA directories -- could they share a parent directory that has multiple PGDATA directories in it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, that is impossible. PostgreSQL protects against that as good as it can, but if you manage to start a second postmaster, instant data corruption will ensue.

This question makes me wonder why you want that:

- It cannot be scalability, because you have I/O as a bottleneck.
- It cannot be high availability, because the shared storage is a single point of failure.

Such architectures like Oracle RAC are ill-conceived and mostly useless; nobody would design such a system these days.

The way to go is a shared-nothing cluster like patroni.